# How to stop other app's music when ever my app plays music

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm working on a music app in objective c. I just want that whenever my app plays music other apps like Spotify's music should be paused.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that using the following:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionInterruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers
                                       error:nil];
```

Hope that helps!